# Unlisted Videos won't play

Tags: android, youtube-api

My unlisted (not private, just unlisted!) videos won't play. Setting the PlayerStateChangeListener revealed, that the videos won't play because of an `INTERNAL_ERROR`:

```
YouTubePlayerSupportFragment fragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();      

getChildFragmentManager()
  .beginTransaction()
  .add(R.id.video, fragment)
  .commit();

fragment.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
   @Override
   public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
        youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoIDForVideoMedia(MY_VIDEO_ID));
        youTubePlayer.setPlayerStateChangeListener(new YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onLoading() {}

           @Override
           public void onLoaded(String s) {}

           @Override
           public void onAdStarted() {}

           @Override
           public void onVideoStarted() {}

           @Override
           public void onVideoEnded() {}

           @Override
           public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason errorReason) {
             Log.e(TAG, errorReason.toString()); // INTERNAL_ERROR right after the video loaded
           }
        });

        // etc...
```

More about errors can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason#Enums).

Any public video id I set for `MY_VIDEO_ID` plays without any problem so far. Has anyone played unlisted videos successfully before?

Comment: Try playing the unlisted youtube video via URL and see if that works. Check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16430530/video-link-of-unlisted-youtube-video) for additional info.

Comment: That doesn't work. You have to set the video Id. That's also what the documentation says. I can however play the video in a webview.... I've settled for that for now...